# Concurrent use of Telerik Ajax and MVC in same Web Site or Web Application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, telerik, telerik-ajax

I am in a situation of needing to transition from Telerik Ajax to MVC without going to the one major release path. In other words, for a period of time, some pages may be using Grid-Ajax and the next page may be using Grid-MVC.

The intent is to have the same release of both. If it does not work for the latest releases, is there a pair of release in the past that will coexist nicely.

I have not been able to find a clear statement about their co-existent.  We are doing classic --> AJAX as a major release because of the relatively minor work required. Going to MVC is not so minor(a lot of tech debt in code base etc).

Answer (score 0):

I really like this question, and at the same time I really hate it.  I am a firm believer in what you are trying to achieve, and you can absolutely use the Telerik AJAX controls in an MVC project.

Check my [One ASP.NET resources](http://bit.ly/fritz1aspnet) for more information about how to make the web forms and MVC play well together.  There is sample code included showing an AJAX grid running in an MVC project.